# the position of overlay is bottom right of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The example in jsfiddle works fine.  But on my page the overlay appears in the bottom - right, out view instead of the centre. Can anyone tell me which sections I need  to change to position overlay in the centre? I've tried bootstrap overlay but this conflicts with current js version, so I thought this solution would be better, that I found on jsfiddle.  I have not  tested it as a responsive feature on mobile etc, but would be good if someone spots anything which might break on mobile and tablet, other os.  Thanks this is the fiddle link and code below http://jsfiddle.net/istvanv/uQj7t/28/

css

```
 a#overlaylaunch-inAbox {
display: block;
padding: 40px;
margin: 40px;
background-color: #efefef;
font-size: 1.6em;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
}

#overlay-inAbox .wrapper {
 text-align: center;
}


/* More important stuff */

.overlay,
#overlay-shade {
display: none;
}

#overlay-shade {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background-color: #000;
 }

.overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 500px;
left: 0;
width: 450px;
min-height: 500px;
z-index: 100;
background-color: #7D7D7D;
border: 10px solid #CFCFCF;
color: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 16px #000;
} .ie7 .overlay {
height: 200px;
} .overlay .wrapper {
padding: 15px 30px 30px;
}


.overlay .toolbar {
padding: 8px;
line-height: 1;
text-align: right;
overflow: hidden;
} .overlay .toolbar a.close {
display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
     zoom: 1;
padding: 0 8px;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 18px;
border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
color: #999999;
background-color: #515151;
 } .overlay .toolbar a.close span {
color: #818181;
} .overlay .toolbar a.close:hover,
.overlay .toolbar a.close:hover span {
background-color: #b90900;
color: #fff;
}
```

js

```
     function openOverlay(olEl) {
    $oLay = $(olEl);

    if ($('#overlay-shade').length == 0)
        $('body').prepend('<div id="overlay-shade"></div>');

    $('#overlay-shade').fadeTo(300, 0.6, function() {
        var props = {
            oLayWidth       : $oLay.width(),
            scrTop          : $(window).scrollTop(),
            viewPortWidth   : $(window).width()
        };

        var leftPos = (props.viewPortWidth - props.oLayWidth) / 2;

        $oLay
            .css({
                display : 'block',
                opacity : 0,
                top : '-=300',
                left : leftPos+'px'
            })
            .animate({
                top : props.scrTop + 40,
                opacity : 1
            }, 600);
    });
}

function closeOverlay() {
    $('.overlay').animate({
        top : '-=300',
        opacity : 0
    }, 400, function() {
        $('#overlay-shade').fadeOut(300);
        $(this).css('display','none');
    });
}

$('#overlay-shade, .overlay a').live('click', function(e) {
    closeOverlay();
    if ($(this).attr('href') == '#') e.preventDefault();
});


// Usage
$('#overlaylaunch-inAbox').click(function(e) {
   openOverlay('#overlay-inAbox');
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

html

```
    <div id="overlay-inAbox" class="overlay">
<div class="toolbar"><a class="close" href="#"><span>x</span> close</a></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    Hello! I'm in a box.
</div>
```

Launch It!

Comment: Have you check to see if you have any conflicting stylesheets or scripts that aren't including in your jsfiddle? Sounds like you've got something overriding your styles.

Comment: nothing called .overlay elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `transform` that centers you all you want without taking care of its dimensions.

```
 .overlay {
     position: fixed;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* ie9 */
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* safari iOS - older androids */
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* all browsers */
 }
```

And that's all. Apply it to all divs you need to center respect the parent. This box is `fixed` position so the parent is the `body` tag.

Note than you don't need javascript calculations, so you can remove them and apply only with css.

### EDIT

As I said in the comments, look at this fiddle with 3 divs perfectly centered without know how are their dimensions. Note than there aren't nothing of javascript to make calculations.

http://jsfiddle.net/11oes0rf/

### EDIT 2

To preserve the top animation as you have in the initial code, you must to specify in percents with the jquery. So the fiddle is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/uQj7t/1363/

And the code is this:

```
$oLay
    .css({
    display : 'block',
    top : '-50%',
    opacity : 0
})
    .animate({
    opacity : 1,
    top: '50%'
}, 600);
```

And closer:

```
function closeOverlay() {
    $('.overlay').animate({
        top: '-50%',
        opacity : 0
    }, 400, function() {
        $('#overlay-shade').fadeOut(300);
        $(this).css('display','none');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has an effect, puts the window top of the screen in desktop, slightly obscured to the the left.  If I experiment with, the percentage top:50% and lef:50% makes no difference to the position?

Comment: are interesting, it seem to work if I have scrolled down a bit, still slightly off centre.  If I have not scrolled it appears right at the top as mentioned

Comment: You must to remove the calculations in javascript, like this piece of code `$oLay
            .css({
                display : 'block',
                opacity : 0,
                top : '-=300',
                left : leftPos+'px'
            })
            .animate({
                top : props.scrTop + 40,
                opacity : 1
            }, 600);`. You can still use the opacity animation (or you can make it by css). You can see this css working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/11oes0rf/ (no matter dimensions of the box, ever will be centered perfectly).

Comment: um, I've remove that code it doesn't work.. I tried adding the example in CSS but that does not work.  Could you edit please edit http://jsfiddle.net/istvanv/uQj7t/28/ so I can see what you mean?

Comment: Maybe this? http://jsfiddle.net/uQj7t/1362/ If you need the animation since the top in open and close, we can make it, but I have no time now, give me 20 minutes

Comment: thanks, that seemed to work, noticed you added the .overlay suggested above after the other css.  Also removed top : '-=300'  from $olay

Comment: Yes, because the translate works with top and left defined to 50%. This is to center perfectly forever. But if you want to conserve the top animation, we can do that. I will update the fiddle today to help you with that

Comment: Here you are the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uQj7t/1363/ I've update my answer

Comment: Right great.  I may pushing my luck but you may know why this it, I've populated the div with a youtube video.  It works, but there is no access to control the video and it closes if I click inside the panel anywhere near the video.  Ican possibly post this somewhere else as could be a new topic.

Comment: You must to open a new question. Paste here the url when it's ready.

Comment: ok thanks I've posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868858/youtube-video-presented-in-overlay-seems-to-close-if-i-click-inside-div