# YouTube video presented in overlay, seems to close if I click inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube

The idea is to play a video automatically in an overlay, after a button click.  The code currently works and plays, however the video **cannot** be controlled inside the div and automatically closes if you click inside the div.

So I need help to make the video inside controllable, the window **not** close when I click on it.

As an extra feature, a good to have would be the overlay window to be responsive depending on the screen size?

***Thanks***

**JS**

```
           $("#play1,#play2,#play3,#play4,#play5").click(function() {

           var value = $( this ).attr( 'track' );

           player.loadVideoById(value,0); 

             // put in overlay window
           openOverlay('#overlay-inAbox');
           e.preventDefault();

           var tag = document.createElement('script');
           tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
           var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


          var player;
          function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
          player = new YT.Player('overlay-inAbox',
          {
          height: '275',
          width: '375',
          events: {

         'onReady': onPlayerReady
                        }
             });
         }
                });
```

**CSS**

```
        function openOverlay(olEl) {
        $oLay = $(olEl);

        if ($('#overlay-shade').length == 0)
        $('body').prepend('<div id="overlay-shade"></div>');

        $('#overlay-shade').fadeTo(300, 0.6, function() {
        var props = {
            oLayWidth       : $oLay.width(),
            scrTop          : $(window).scrollTop(),
            viewPortWidth   : $(window).width()
        };

        var leftPos = (props.viewPortWidth - props.oLayWidth) / 2;

        $oLay
            .css({
                display : 'block',
                top : '-50%',
                opacity : 0
            })
            .animate({
                opacity : 1,
                top: '50%'
            }, 600);
    });
}

    function closeOverlay() {
    $('.overlay').animate({
        top: '-50%',
        opacity : 0
    }, 400, function() {
        $('#overlay-shade').fadeOut(300);
        $(this).css('display','none');
    });
}

$('#overlay-shade, .overlay a').live('click', function(e) {
    closeOverlay();
    if ($(this).attr('href') == '#') e.preventDefault();
});


// Usage
$('#overlaylaunch-inAbox').click(function(e) {
   openOverlay('#overlay-inAbox');
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I'd have to see your html to be sure, but i'd imagine it's your on-click code `$('#overlay-shade, .overlay a').live('click', function(e) {` is being triggered when clicking on the youtube player and closing the overlay. Maybe try putting in a close button or having it close when clicking outside the overlay?

Comment: as @gaynorvader said, the closing function may causes conflict. The best is to put a classname or and id in the closing button to avoid to target all `<a>` tags. Something like `<a id="closeButton">` and in the js `$('overlay-shade, .overlay #closeButton')`

Comment: it turned out to be because I did not close a </div>